What is this formula? Area of Jordan curve
I came across the following area formula in do Carmo's book:

I tried searching online for where this formula came from, but I couldn't find anything that matched this. Does anyone have a name for the highlighted part, or know how it might be derived?

there is a standard area thing based on Green's theorem.  It is the basis of a drafting tool called a planimeter.  https://people.math.harvard.edu/~knill/teaching/math21a2000/planimeter/index.html

https://mathinsight.org/greens_theorem_find_area

Got it. Thanks!
